# Writing to Text Box keeps failing - Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox

Apologies if this is an easy mistake, quite new to VB but not sure where I am going wrong. My code produces results which I are to be written to textboxes at the end of the process. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub ButtonInput_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonInput.Click
        Try
            'information irrelevant to question here..

            MainMethod.Main()

            TextBoxbf.AppendText(bestGlobalFitness.ToString("F4"))
            TextBox0.Text = bestGlobalPosition(0)
            TextBox1.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(1).ToString("F4"))
            TextBox2.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(2).ToString("F4"))
            TextBox3.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(3).ToString("F4"))
            TextBox4.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(4).ToString("F4"))
            TextBox5.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(5).ToString("F4"))
            TextBox6.AppendText(bestGlobalPosition(6).ToString("F4"))

        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            Console.WriteLine("IndexOutOfRangeException caught")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I have tried both the TextBox.Text and TextBox.AppendText methods but neither appear to be working. What is somewhat odd is that the first line TextBoxbf.AppendText(bestGlobalFitness.ToString("F4")) does work..

Here is how bestGlobalPosition and bestGlobalFitness are entered in the Module:

```
Module MainMethod
    Public bestGlobalFitness As Double
    Public bestGlobalPosition([Dim] - 1) As Double
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim bestGlobalPosition([Dim] - 1) As Double
        bestGlobalFitness = Double.MaxValue

        'rest of method here..

        Console.Write("Final best fitness = ")
        Console.WriteLine(bestGlobalFitness.ToString("F4"))
        For i As Integer = 0 To bestGlobalPosition.Length - 1
            Console.Write("x" & i & " = ")
            Console.WriteLine(bestGlobalPosition(i).ToString("F4") & " ")
```

I really can't see where I am going wrong - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you turned on option strict and explicit in the VB compiler options? You're also hiding any other potential exceptions by only providing a catch for an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Could you add another generic catch after the first one? I.e.
`Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException blah blah Catch ex As Exception blah blah End Try`

Comment: @Sean, I tried swapping from Explicit to Strict but to no avail. The result is the same - first text box fills up, the others do not. Also, I tried adding another catch as you have mentioned, but there was no other exception caught.. Really stumped on this!

Comment: Hmm. Can you alert the values you get from the array before you try to set the textbox text? E.g. `MessageBox.Show(bestGlobalPosition(0)) TextBox0.Text = bestGlobalPosition(0)` and also try changing that line to `TextBox0.Text = bestGlobalPosition(0).ToString()`?